# Equivalent Bash command to this Batch

Tags: bash, macos, shell, scripting

I have this command :

```
for /D %%D in ("%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*") do xcopy /y %SourceFile% "%%D\Extensions\"
```

(Send the file to the sub folder "Extensions" in each of the folders under the wanted path)

And I need to do the same with bash. I tried :

```
for i in "/Users/XUser/Library/Application\ \Support/Firefox/Profiles/*"; do
    cp "/Users/Xuser/Desktop/Extension@tgo.com.xpi" "$i"
done
```

but `*` doesn't apply here for all folder and I don't know how to do the equivalent for `"%%D\Extensions\"`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't quote the wildcard. If it's in quotes then it's a literal asterisk rather than a glob.

```
for i in /Users/XUser/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/Profiles/*; do
    cp /Users/Xuser/Desktop/Extension@tgo.com.xpi "$i"
done
```

Comment: I'd also recommend adding a "/" to the end of the pattern (`/Users/XUser/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/Profiles/*/`) to make it match only directories, not plain files.

Comment: But this command will send the file to Profile folder
I need to send it to a subfolder inside named Exttesnions